# Ghost With Nginx Only Works on Port 80

Tags: nginx, node.js

I've been struggling to get this fixed since yesterday. I've done a lot to try and resolve it and still nothing seams to work. I am trying to install NodeJS with Ghost and use NGINX as a reverse proxy for each one of my apps (Ghost in this case), but I don't want it to run on port 80. However, it only works on port 80. As soon as I change the `listen` option within the configuration file to something other than 80 it stops working.

So here is my setup

- Running Ubuntu 14.04.04 x64 VPS
- Configuration files are in sites-available with a symbolic link to sites-enabled
- There is no default file in sites-enabled and there are no files inside /etc/nginx/conf.d
- I haven't changed anything in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
- Firewall is disabled and files are in /www/domain.com folder with permission 777 owned by root:root (i'll adjust the permissions when I get it working)
- Ghost is running on port 9020 and host is 0.0.0.0 (both inside config.js)

So my configuration file inside sites-available is:
(works fine unless I change `listen 80 default_server` to `listen 9000 default_server` or any other port.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name x.net www.x.net;

    root /www/x.net;
        index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9020;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

When listening to port 9000 when I type `netstat -peanut` in the console this is my result;

[netstat -peanut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LgEq.png)

Suggestions why it isnt working?

Comment: You screenshot shows Nginx listening on port 9000, so that implies the configuration file is being read. So what exactly happens when you use 9000? What do the logs show for nginx

Comment: @Drifter104 Thanks for trying to help out. When I use port 9000 and I navigate to mydomain.com Ghost doesn't load. But when I specify the port after the domain (domain.com:9000), then Ghost shows up. However, I when I use the standard port 80 then I don't need to specify the port in the domain name. It just works. I want the same behaviour when using port 9000. When Ghost doesn't load (when not specifying port 9000) there is nothing being logged in the nginx log file (/var/log/nginx/error.log) which makes it hard to find out exactly whats wrong

Comment: That's exactly what "standard port" means. If you don't want the port in the URL, you use port 80. Full stop.